# Invalid Column Name Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm going through different questions but unable to get solution. Sometimes it works perfectly fine but for some queries it gives error of invalid column name.

Column is not a FK. It's simply a nullable string of type `varchar(50)`.

I've deleted table from schema and re-add it but getting same issue.

Code is simple. I'm getting data on ID basis where ID is PK.

```
bkItem item = (from objDB in dataContext.bkItems
               where objDB.id == itemId
               select objDB).ToList();
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Invalid column name would suggest that there *is* a problem with the schema. Check you have a working compiled schema after you have changed the table - you should save the .dbml file and have no errors or warnings.

Comment: Just noticed ``` ... ).ToList().FirstOrDefault();``` That's VERY inefficient, just use .FirstOrDefault() only

Comment: schema is in working condition

Comment: o yeah that is inefficient. thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: The schema isn't working or you would not have an error! Check it again. Open the DBML file using a text editor and look at the <Columns> definition for each column and compare with the database. Are you using dev/test/production environments? Are the databases the same?

Comment: Everything is perfectly OK. Code is working fine for test environment but for production it gives error. Column definition is also same for each column.